# Nginx proxing files from

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I try to serve angular application from azure blob, the problem is that I cannot proxy with URI and regex.

My configuration was:

```
 location /web {
 proxy_pass https://blob.com/web/index.html;
}

location ^~ /monitor {
 proxy_pass https://blob2.net/angular/index.html;
}

location ~* \.(js|map|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$ {
 proxy_pass https://blob2.net/angular;
    }
```

The JS files should come from blob2/angular as they are located there. But with this configuration I have exception "proxy_pass cannot have URI part...", that means proxy_path can't have uri with regex. Ok, so I changed the last statement to:

```
  location ~* \.(js|map|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$ {
rewrite ^ /angular$1;
proxy_pass https://blob2.net;
    }
```

But still doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
Changed configuration to

```
    location ~* (\.(?:js|map|jpe?g|png|ico))$ {
 proxy_pass https://angularweb.blob.core.windows.net/angular/$1;
    }
```

But now the files are 404. In log there is nothing just "31.168.50.6 - - [13/Jun/2017:10:28:53 +0000] "GET /inline.bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleW$"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this location block:

```
location ~* (\.(?:js|map|jpe?g|png|ico)$ {
    proxy_pass https://blob2.net/angular/$1;
}
```

Here we capture the file name for the file to `$1` variable, which is then used in the `proxy_pass` destination.

I also combined `jpeg` and `jpg` in the regex, and made the regex group of suffixes non-capturing by adding `?:` to the start of the expression.

Comment: It doesn't through the error, but the files are 404 now. It's strange, it should work.

Comment: You need to check the application server logs on what URLs it sees on the requests and then see if those URLs work when requested directly from the application server. If you cannot figure out the issue directly, add that information to the question.

Comment: Updated to question. The log doesn't show much.

Comment: Is that really the application server log? And you need to include an application server log for the direct request case when it works correctly.